# Win10 Pro/Hyper-V cannot start any machines, "failed to power on: system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

Windows 10 Pro, v1803 Build 17134.648, 64-bit. Hyper-V Manager v10.0.17134.1.

I have had Hyper-V running on my Windows 10 machine for many months, but recently have had an error when starting my VMs up: Microsoft VmBus (Instance ID [long GUID]): Failed to Power on with Error 'The system cannot find the path specified.'.

(Note: I have moved my default Virtual Hard Disks and Virtual Machines folders to a harddrive that is not my C: due to space limitations.)

(clarification) While Hyper-V can see existing and new VMs, it cannot start any of them without throwing the above error.  This applies to machine that pre-existed prior to the first error, or were newly created using Quick Create (with default settings.)  There are no devices in the VM settings that indicate they are in error, and the VHD is found in the location the settings indicate it should be.

I have no idea what the path is that it's claiming it cannot find.  I can find confirmation in the Event Logs, but no additional clues.  In Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/Hyper-V-Worker/Admin, I see the two error event IDs 12010 ['Windows 10 Dev Environment' Microsoft VmBus: Failed to Power on with Error 'The system cannot find the path specified.' (0x80070003).] and 10230 ['Windows 10 Dev Environment' failed to start.].

Can someone please give me a clue where I can look to confirm what "path specified" it's looking for, and how I can provide it, or change it?

Comment: Can those who are voting this down please explain *why*?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: Windows 10 Pro, v1803 Build 17134.648, 64-bit.  
Hyper-V Manager v10.0.17134.1.  
Windows 10 dev environment created using Quick Create, no NIC attached.

Comment: Using ProcMon, I am seeing calls to RegOpenKey for HKCR\CLSID\{0c172fd4-1b2a-11da-994c-0008744f51f3}, but a manual search through the registry doesn't show that GUID referenced anywhere.  Also HKCR\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{0c172fd4-1b2a-11da-994c-0008744f51f3}.  It's possible that this is the "path" that is missing, but where else can I look to find why it's looking for this GUID, and how I can set/reset it?

Comment: Does anyone have instructions on how to reset all Hyper-V settings after an uninstall, so when you reinstall Hyper-V it doesn't see *any* of the settings or paths that were used previously?

Comment: Nope - Uninstalled Hyper-V, renamed all associated Hyper-V folders, reinstalled Hyper-V, Quick Create the Ubuntu environment, try to start up, and... same error :-(

'Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS' Microsoft VmBus (Instance ID D41A1872-3740-41CE-A1EE-4522AB82F991): Failed to Power on with Error 'The system cannot find the path specified.' (0x80070003). (Virtual machine ID 0449CD6D-1B32-44CB-B9D7-64D53C6015DA)

Comment: you could try installing hyper-v in the other drive as well (ive had a few problems with scripts not being able to open cross drive links)

Comment: could also be that the path is simply too long I found this :

This "System cannot find the path specified" error can be caused by exceeding the limit of the path length. Windows limits file paths to 256 characters.

Comment: Are your VMs (config) & hard disks in separate disks? I had a similar problem. But creating a new VM & changing the hyper-v default folder paths somehow fixed the problem.

Comment: @jonathan-heindl How did you install Hyper-V on a drive that isn't the system drive?  I don't see any option for that, only for Turning the Feature On or Off?  As for the path being too long, it won't be that, as the VMs and all VHD files are only one level off root, in folders with very short names.

Comment: @DxTx The VMs and the VHDs are on the same drive, they're just not the C: drive.  However, as this is affecting old machines and new, I do not think this is the issue.  But, stranger things have happened, so I will try moving the settings for the VMs and VHDs around a bit, to see if that makes any positive difference.

Comment: @Dan oh sorry not Hyper-V I meant whatever  tool you use to manage your vms

Comment: @jonathan-heindl I am using the Hyper-V Manager that comes with the standard Windows feature.  Maybe using a different management tool could help -- do you have any recommendations?

Comment: @Dan well I was using virtualbox for the most part as far as I know it also runs with Hyper-V (I has to deactivate it as I have a amd cpu at home )  another idea I have is searching the registry on wether there are references to the old location of the vhds

Comment: @Dan and jsut to confirm on wether sometihng might be completely broken you can try moving them back temporary and check if it starts working again if it does this link might be helpful https://forums.servethehome.com/index.php?threads/hyperv-move-vms-from-one-drive-to-another.13527/

Comment: on top of that maybe the vhd paths are setup relative to the hyper-v manager default vhd folder then you could go into settings and try changing it to the new drive

Comment: @jonathan-heindl Unfortunately, moving the VM in question (or, rather, a VM that I expressly created using Quick Create for testing solutions to this problem) from the drive where it was back to the C: drive did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you please open event viewer and lookup for the related error/warning events in the Custom Views -> Administrative Events and Application and Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Hyper-V-*.

For each suspicious event found please provide all information copy/pasted from the Details -> Friendly View with all records of data expanded. Maybe you could create a TXT file and attach a link to it to your question.

Comment: @sergey-nudnov, all relevant Event View log details were included in the original post: "I can find confirmation in the Event Logs, but no additional clues. In Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/Hyper-V-Worker/Admin, I see the two error event IDs 12010 ['Windows 10 Dev Environment' Microsoft VmBus: Failed to Power on with Error 'The system cannot find the path specified.' (0x80070003).] and 10230 ['Windows 10 Dev Environment' failed to start.]."

Comment: Thanks to all who tried to help, but I have since abandoned this entirely.  I have purchased a new machine, which I will be installing a new Windows 10 environment onto, and will start Hyper-V completely from scratch on that box, then after confirming that Hyper-V functions correctly, I will import my VMs to there.

Comment: @Dan, to resolve your question I was trying to look up the Hyper-V for binaries for `Failed to Power on` message, but failed to find any. That was a reason I asked to provide me Event Viewer events with **all information copy/pasted from the Details -> Friendly View with all records of data expanded**.  I tried to locate a module, generating the events. It doesn't matter now, as you abandoned a question. But overall, next time try to provide the exact details requested. That will help people trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who tried to help, but I have since abandoned this entirely.  I have purchased a new machine, which I will be installing a new Windows 10 environment onto, and will start Hyper-V completely from scratch on that box, then after confirming that Hyper-V functions correctly, I will import my VMs to there.